# Cut Specific Cells, Refresh Pivot, then Paste Cells after Pivot

Tags: excel, vba

I have three rows of data placed just after a pivot table. I am trying to create a single process to cut that data, prior to a pivot table refresh and then paste after the pivot table has been refreshed. The pivot table occupies columns B-I, and the cells occupy the same columns. I have one row of separation between the end of the pivot table and the three rows of data.

Comment: What have you tried thusfar?  If you haven't made any progress yourself, try the `Macro Recorder` in the *Development* tab of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is one of those things that's tricky because you need to know how big the pivot will get *after* the refresh, but you need to know it *before* it refreshes.

I think you might as well just insert a bunch of rows between your data and the pivot, refresh the pivot safely, and then remove the extra rows.

```
Sub RefreshButPreserveFooterRows()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim PivotOriginalEndPosition As Integer
    Dim PivotRefreshedEndPosition As Integer
    Dim safetyGap

    'pick how many rows you want to insert.  Might as well be generous.
    safetyGap = 100
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

    'Deterimine the position of the first row after your pivot table prior to refresh
    PivotOriginalEndPosition = pt.RowRange.Rows.Count + pt.RowRange.Row

    'Insert howerver many rows you specified as "Safety Gap" between your pivot and your data
    Rows(PivotOriginalEndPosition & ":" & PivotOriginalEndPosition + safetyGap).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    'refresh the pivot
    pt.RefreshTable

    'Deterimine the position of the first row after your pivot table after to refresh
    PivotRefreshedEndPosition = pt.RowRange.Rows.Count + pt.RowRange.Row

    'delete the extra rows from the safety gap, accounting for the new size of the pivot table
    Rows(PivotRefreshedEndPosition & ":" & PivotOriginalEndPosition + safetyGap).Delete

End Sub
```